Go router package nested page navigation problem in my Flutter application
I want to include the go router package in my flutter project, but I'm having trouble because I'm very new to this subject. The problem I'm having is that I created nested pages and when you give this kind of sub-page, a back button is automatically created in the appbar. When I click on this back button, it prints the same page again, while I expect it to return to the previous page.
below I share my code with you
class AppNavigation {
  AppNavigation._();

  static String initial = "/splashScreen";

  // Private navigators
  static final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final _shellNavigatorHome =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellHome');
  static final _shellNavigatorHomePageForBidder =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellHomePageForBidder');
  static final _shellNavigatorBuyVehicleCategory =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellNavigatorBuyVehicleCategory');
  static final _shellNavigatorSellCarPage =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellNavigatorSellCarPage');
  static final _shellNavigatorServicesPage =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellNavigatorServicesPage');
  static final _shellNavigatorMyOffersPage =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellNavigatorMyOffersPage');
  static final _shellNavigatorMyFavCars =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellNavigatorMyFavCars');
  static final _shellNavigatorMyCarsList =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellNavigatorMyCarsList');
  static final _shellNavigatorMessages =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellMessages');
  static final _shellNavigatorNotifications =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'shellNotifications');

  // GoRouter configuration
  static final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: initial,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    routes: [
      /// MainWrapper
      StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
        builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
          return MainPage(
            navigationShell: navigationShell,
          );
        },
        branches: <StatefulShellBranch>[
          /// Brach Home
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorHome,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/homePage",
                name: "HomePage",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const HomePage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorHomePageForBidder,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/homePageForBidder",
                name: "HomePageForBidder",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const HomePageForBidder(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorBuyVehicleCategory,
            routes: <GoRoute>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/buyVehicleCategory",
                name: "BuyVehicleCategory",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  return const BuyVehicleCategory();
                },
                routes: <GoRoute>[
                  GoRoute(
                    path: "buySubVehicleCategory",
                    name: "BuySubVehicleCategory",
                    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                      final CategoryModel params = state.extra as CategoryModel;
                      return BuySubVehicleCategory(
                        categoryModel: params,
                      );
                    },
                    routes: <GoRoute>[
                      GoRoute(
                        path: "buyCarPage",
                        name: "BuyCarPage",
                        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                          final CategoryModel params =
                              state.extra as CategoryModel;
                          final int jobCategoryId = params.id!;
                          return BuyCarPage(jobCategoryId: jobCategoryId);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorSellCarPage,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/sellCarPage",
                name: "SellCarPage",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const SellCarPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorServicesPage,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/servicesPage",
                name: "ServicesPage",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const ServicesPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorMyOffersPage,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/myOffersPage",
                name: "MyOffersPage",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const MyOffersPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorMyFavCars,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/myFavCarsListPage",
                name: "MyFavCarsListPage",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const MyFavCarsListPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorMyCarsList,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/myCarsListingPage",
                name: "MyCarsListingPage",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const MyCarsListingPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          /// Brach Setting
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorMessages,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/messagesPage",
                name: "MessagesPage",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const MessagesPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          /// Brach Setting
          StatefulShellBranch(
            navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorNotifications,
            routes: <RouteBase>[
              GoRoute(
                path: "/notificationsPage",
                name: "NotificationsPage",
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
                    const NotificationsPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/splashScreen',
        name: "Splash",
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
            const SplashPage(),
      ),

      GoRoute(
          path: '/carDetailPage',
          name: "CarDetailPage",
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            final Map<String, dynamic> params =
                state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>;
            final int jobId = params['jobId'];
            final CustomerViewModel customerViewModel =
                params['customerViewModel'];
            final String title = params['title'];
            final Customer? customer = params['customer'];
            final VoidCallback onJobStatusChanged =
                params['onJobStatusChanged'];

            return CarDetailPage(
              title: title,
              customer: customer,
              jobId: jobId,
              customerViewModel: customerViewModel,
              onJobStatusChanged: onJobStatusChanged,
            );
          }),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/screenSelection',
        name: "ScreenSelection",
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
            const ScreenSelection(),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

The part I have a problem with is the BuyVehicleCategory and its subpages
I changed the navigator keys and Parent keys, sometimes I used the same and sometimes I used different keys but I could not get a result.

Please check if you are using the correct path to navigate or not:
Correct Way:
 context.push(ParentRoute+'/'+ChildRoute);

Incorrect Way:
 context.push(ChildRoute);

